# Grok pattern working fine in grok debugger but the same pattern is not working when running with logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

```
**Input File:**

123.123.12.123 - - [09/Jan/2021:00:00:41 -0500] "GET /abcde/common/abcde.jsp HTTP/1.1" 401 1944 1
```

Output in Grok Debugger
{
"Path": "GET /abcde/common/abcde.jsp HTTP/1.1",
"ResponseCode": "401",
"KnowCode": "1944",
"ExitCode": "1",
"UserInfo": "-",
"HostName": "123.123.12.123",
"Date": "09/Jan/2021:00:00:41 -0500"
}

**GROK filter in logstash**

```
grok {
    match => {"message" => " %{IP:HostName}\s\-\s%{USERNAME:UserInfo}\s\[%{GREEDYDATA:Date}\]\s\"%{GREEDYDATA:Path}\"\s%{BASE10NUM:ResponseCode}\s%{BASE10NUM:KnowCode}\s%{BASE10NUM:ExitCode}"}
}
```

**Whereas when process same grok pattern in logstash filter in Kibana screen it gives me result like this ::**

```
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-02-12T16:38:28.141Z,
          "type" => "access_logs",
          "path" => "C:/Temp/BOHLogs/CatalinaAccess/localhost_access_log.2021-01-09.txt",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
          "host" => "AB-1SM433",
       "message" => "123.123.12.123 - - [09/Jan/2021:00:00:41 -0500] \"GET /abcde/common/abcde.jsp HTTP/1.1\" 401 1944 1"
```

Comment: Same grok pettern when using in logstash file, its not generating result in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space at the start of your pattern that needs to be removed.

```
grok {
    match => {"message" => " %{IP:HostName}\s\-\s%{USERNAME:UserInfo}\s\[%{GREEDYDATA:Date}\]\s\"%{GREEDYDATA:Path}\"\s%{BASE10NUM:ResponseCode}\s%{BASE10NUM:KnowCode}\s%{BASE10NUM:ExitCode}"}
                            ^ Delete this
}
```